# virtualbox ubuntu 12.04.01 ran out of space and will not reboot

Tags: virtualbox

I was using my Ubuntu 12.04.1 virtualbox yesterday, and while installing some software, it gave me a warning about low disk space. I shut the laptop down and this morning the virtual machine will not reboot. It starts by complaining about low-resolution graphics and gives me the option of reconfiguring them.

The machine is I believe reached the maximum disk space I allocated for it, which is why it's not able to reboot:

[image]

The machine stays like this when I choose "run in low-res mode":

[image]

This is what storage tells me about the status of the machine:

[image]

Virtualbox itself is working on my Windows 7 laptop at work (not my choice unfortunately), so I closed virtualbox and tried to resize the machine with this command:

[image]

The resize was successful and I tried to reboot the machine again after it, but the same low-graphics mode menu appears.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

you have re-sized your disk but not the partition ;-). Open your virtual machine with knoppix and use gparted or similar to re-size the partition in order to use all your disk space.