# Recovery lost files ubuntu vdi

Tags: virtualbox, data-recovery, vdi

I recently deleted a few files from my virtual machine, without any backup.

It was a terrible mistake and now I need recover them.

If I move the `.vdi` file to an external disk, is it possible to run knoppix and try to recover the files? It's a fixed size VDI and when the fatality happened it was no longer touched.

My questions are, is there any hope? Should I move the VDI or can I copy it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover files from a broken Virtualbox machine .vdi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425518/recover-files-from-a-broken-virtualbox-machine-vdi) and [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Yes, you are write! Maybe the solution can solve my problem! I will remove my question.