# Is there a way to recover a files deleted on Ubuntu system that's running in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, data-recovery, data-loss, vdi

I need help recovering my accidentally deleted files.

I'm running an Ubuntu OS inside a Virtualbox virtual machine and accidentally deleted a folder. I had a venv in my home directory that got deleted and its not in trash. The way it got deleted was I was trying to create a new profile for Firefox and set the profile directory to my venv. The venv got populated with a whole bunch of Firefox files which I didn't want in there so I deleted my profile on Firefox along with all files. I thought it would just delete the Firefox files but it deleted my entire directory.

Is there a way I can recover these files? I searched for an answer online and tried testdisk but the deleted files never appeared. It seems it may be very difficult or impossible to recover files deleted on a virtual machine.

Comment: Have you seen this, might be closest to your problem.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/425518/recover-files-from-a-broken-virtualbox-machine-vdi?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover files from a broken Virtualbox machine .vdi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425518/recover-files-from-a-broken-virtualbox-machine-vdi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)